# Почему Функциональное программирование - это самостоятельная парадигма, а не разновидность декларативной?

Tags: ооп, информатика

Никак не могу понять, ООП это парадигма или нет? Вроде как это разновидность императивной парадигмы. Это выглядит логично. Но тогда есть 2 основные парадигмы: императивная и декларативная. И значит ФП должно считаться разновидностью декларативной. Но ФП почему то все выделяют как самостоятельную парадигму

Comment: Да какая разница? Я вот думал писать на хаскеле, но у меня вовремя появилась трезвая мысль: чтобы писать на хаскеле эффективно, нужно уметь в триксы типа написания рекурсии через комбинаторы, использование ленивости, иначе код будет слишком медленный. Но даже тогда хаскель не превзойдет по скорости C++. Тогда зачем он нужен? И все прочие функциональные языки.

Comment: @typemoon,  я не про функциональные языки, а про функциональное программирование

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> И значит ФП должно считаться разновидностью декларативной.

[Английская википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming#Functional_programming) утверждает, что так и есть.

> Но ФП почему то все выделяют как самостоятельную парадигму

**А это уже контекст *беседы*** и насколько в ней есть смысл говорить о декларативной парадигме вообще. Обычно нет, поскольку это слишком широкое понятие и содержит мало информации. В беседе лучше использовать более конкретный и точный термин (а желательно ещё и не менее известный), чтобы донести информацию лучше.

---

### А вообще...

...парадигма как таковая это просто набор идей. Под "разновидностью парадигмы Х" вы, вероятно, понимаете набор идей, включающий целиком набор идей Х.

> ООП это парадигма или нет? Вроде как это разновидность императивной парадигмы.

**Да, парадигма. Нет, не разновидность императивной.**

ООП как парадигма описывает лишь способ организации данных (объекты) и их "форм" (классы), а также возможность создания новых "форм" (наследников), наследующих свойства предка(-ов).

Данные определённой "формы" и комплект действий для них предназначаются для решения некоей задачи, для чего не требуется знать о задаче ничего, что не касается **условия задачи** и **результата**. Деталей решения знать не нужно (теоретически, в реальности это полезно).

**Императивная** парадигма это набор идей об описании действий с помощью инструкций, вносящих изменения в имеющиеся данные. Какой формы при этом данные, не регламентируется.

**Эти два набора идей не имеют значительного пересечения.** Просто так вышло, что самые популярные ныне объектно-ориентированные языки реализуют именно императивный подход, скорее всего потому что он **технически проще реализуется**. *Но парадигме нельзя приписывать черты её реализаций, потому что завтра человек может эту же парадигму применить без них.*

> Но тогда есть 2 основные парадигмы: императивная и декларативная.

Тут неловко вышло... **Декларативная [часто определяется](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming#Definition), как "не императивная"**, в результате чего теряется контекст, а к термину относят пугающее количество вещей, **многие из которых не имеют отношения к программированию**.

Но если говорить о программах, то это два способа описания действия "из А получить Б":

- Описать, что надо сделать с А, чтобы получить Б (императивный)
- Описать, что такое Б, пользуясь известным А (декларативный)

Comment: Я бы "вытащил" (можно и сдублировать), собственно ответ (вместе с английской вики) наверх, а потом уже привел весь остальной текст. А то сам ответ на вопрос как-то теряется.

Comment: @avp ну, я тут вижу несколько вопросов и отвечаю в порядке следования, закрепляясь по цитатам.

Comment: А сам заголовок? IMHO это и есть основной вопрос.

Comment: @avp осмысленно, хотя это лишь "краткий пересказ". Перебросьте :) Ну или дождитесь меня, я просто не рискну это сделать с телефона.

Comment: Я не спешу (и вообще, я ленивый, ответы не горят, а лучше автора никто с текстом не справится) -).

Comment: @D-side, я еще очень часто слышал мнение что можно разделить по следующему принципу: используется присваивание или нет. В императивной используется, а в декларативной нет. И вроде как это их главное отличие. Что вы об этом скажете?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров важнее другое: в ФП не принято "записывать поверх". Да, это исключает многие случаи присваивания, но не все. Там есть концепция "связывания" значения с именем, связка в одном контексте не меняется. Часто выглядит очень похоже.

Comment: @D-side, не понял( ну связывание да, есть конечно, но это по сути константы же.. Я имел в виду не то что оператора = нет. Конечно же я другое имел в виду. То что в ФП нет зависимости от времени. И вот это вроде бы действительно так, и это можно считать главным отличием? С этой точки зрения можно считать ООП разновидностью императивной парадигмы?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров ФПшные значения вполне могут быть запакованы в объекты, операции над которыми возвращают новые объекты с применённой операцией. Персистентные структуры данных, например. Так что нет, нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос, который заставляет задуматься и вспомнить что такое парадигма? Парадигма - это совокупность идей и понятий, определяющих стиль написания программ. Давайте посмотрим на ООП. Программа состоит из объектов, связанных друг с другом ссылками. Вы создаете целый граф объектов. Основной тред проходит по этому графу и выполняет инструкции. Программист указывает треду что ему делать. Важный момент в том, что граф может меняться в процессе выполнения инструкций и программист должен предусмотреть изменения и реагировать на них должным образом.
Теперь посмотрим на декларативный стиль. Программист оперирует инструкциями более высокого уровня. Возьмем у примеру WPF. В XAML вы можете написать просто Window. Тоже самое на языке C# записывается несколько подробнее. 
И наконец мы пришли к функциональному стилю. Его особенность в том, что программа по виду приближена к математическим выражениям. В которых есть функции, вызывающие функции, возвращающие функции и так далее. 
Обратите внимание, что у каждого из стилей есть особенности отличные от других. В итоге можно сказать, что ООП - это парадигма.